# ¿Como verifico si dos indices de dos listas son iguales?

Tags: python

Es un problema en python. Además de verificar que sean iguales, necesito meter los número de esos indices en una lista.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola,

La pregunta está mal elaborada, por favor lee la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Por favor añade más información a tu problema (Tamaño de los arreglos, si son del mismo tamaño, etc) y el código que actualmente tienes

Comment: ¿Qué es eso de dos índices de dos listas que son iguales? Una lista de 5 elementos tiene 5 índices. Otra lista de 7 elementos tiene 7 índices. Los índices del 0 al 4 son obviamente iguales en ambas listas (aunque sus contenidos no lo sean). No entiendo a qué te refires. Querrás decir si dos elementos son iguales y en ese caso almacenar sus índices? Mejor pones un ejemplo de las entradas y salidas deseadas

Comment: a que te refieres con verificar que sean iguales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que el indice esté presente en ambas listas, puedes hacer esta condicion.

```
print(lista1[index] == lista2[index])
```